# Change default home dir of user

Tags: linux, centos, home-directory, usermod

I want to change the default home directory of a user from this:

```
User: john
Default home: /home/john
```

To this:

```
User: john
Home: /var/www/project/new-home
```

How could i do that?

What i've tried so far is use usermod:

```
usermod -m -d /var/www/project/john john
```

It worked for one user, but i've got two users, john & sarah, and when i tried the same for sarah it said:

```
usermod: no changes
```

Comment: I understand why you might want to do that, but you should just put the website under /home/username/html or public_html, this is how cpanel and interworx (and likely others) separate userspace, also check out         SuexecUserGroup

Comment: Oh, no that's not what i want to do, i'm using pure-ftpd and it's configured to chroot users to their home dir, so basically one user is for the frontend files, and the other is for the backend files, i just want the users to navigate through their files, not to be able to navigate upper their dir @JacobEvans

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea why usermod doesn't work but it doesn't really matter. You can easily review & edit `/etc/passwd` and make the necessary change if required. Then move their existing home directory over to  /var/www/project/ if desired.